# How does Ingress request dispatching works in Kubernetes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I'm working on a project where i need a front-end in angular and a back-end with spring-boot.
I've made 2 docker images for them, and used an ingress like the following to dipatch requests to the correct service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: smf-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: rest-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service: 
                name: ng-service
                port:
                  number: 4200
```

As you see, all requests matching '/api*' are redirected to the rest-service, which is my spring boot application.

If i make a request, say '/api/helloworld', to the ingress, **how is this request modified before reaching spring endpoints?**
Will spring receive the same request, calling an endpoint mapped to '/api/helloworld' or not?

I'm asking this because I mapped my endpoints in spring to '/api/some_endpoint' , but every time i try to access those urls from the browser i get spring error page (404).
To achieve this behavior I set the following property in my spring boot application:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

is this wrong? why? can you explain me a solution?

Comment: Please add the output of the following in your question
kubectl get svc -o wide 
and 
kubectl get ep

Answer (score 1):

First some context, Kubernetes does not include an Ingress Controller so this all specific to ingress-nginx, which I assume you are running given the annotation you are asking about is specific to that project. Other Ingress Controllers will work differently.

That said, you can find the documentation for the rewrite feature here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#deployment. The rewrite is implemented in Nginx, more specifically the ingress-nginx controller takes all your Ingress objects and generates an nginx config file, which is then handed off to normal standard nginx as the proxy.

The behavior you have there will be equivalent to `s|^/api|/|`, however as noted in the docs the behavior changed in version 0.22 so if you're on a newer version that probably wouldn't work as you expect.